# How to detect what is causing entries in the "last" cmd's output?

Tags: openbsd, last

```
last
...
date      {                                 Sun Mar 31 12:00
date      |                                 Sun Mar 31 12:00
date      {                                 Sun Mar 31 00:00
date      |                                 Sun Mar 31 00:00
...
```

Why are there e.x.: "{" in the last commands output? Some sort of script could do this? (on OpenBSD 5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines you are seeing indicate the system time has been automatically updated. The '|' character indicates the time prior to the change and the '{' character indicates the new time.

Source: man utmp (5)

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `strace last` to find out what exactly is making the output containing `{` and `|` characters.

Comment: That will only tell you why it printed it, not what caused it to be in the log in the first place.